Python how to pull data from dictionary
Using the weerlive.nl API to pull weather data from the Dutch meteriological institute (KNMI), I get a dictionary with one key 'liveweer' with a long set of tuples:
dict_values([[{'plaats': 'Tilburg', 'timestamp': '1713019987', 'time': '13-04-2024 16:53', 'temp': '23.3', 'gtemp': '22.3', 'samenv': 'Licht bewolkt', 'lv': '48', 'windr': 'ZW', 'windrgr': '225', 'windms': '6', 'winds': '4', 'windk': '11.7', 'windkmh': '21.6', 'luchtd': '1020.5', 'ldmmhg': '765', 'dauwp': '11.7', 'zicht': '40', 'verw': 'Vandaag zonnige perioden, droog en vrij warm. Zondag frisser', 'sup': '06:45', 'sunder': '20:35', 'image': 'lichtbewolkt', 'd0weer': 'bewolkt', 'd0tmax': '22', 'd0tmin': '12', 'd0windk': '3', 'd0windknp': '10', 'd0windms': '5', 'd0windkmh': '19', 'd0windr': 'ZW', 'd0windrgr': '225', 'd0neerslag': '0', 'd0zon': '0', 'd1weer': 'halfbewolkt', 'd1tmax': '15', 'd1tmin': '10', 'd1windk': '3', 'd1windknp': '8', 'd1windms': '4', 'd1windkmh': '15', 'd1windr': 'W', 'd1windrgr': '270', 'd1neerslag': '20', 'd1zon': '50', 'd2weer': 'regen', 'd2tmax': '11', 'd2tmin': '7', 'd2windk': '3', 'd2windknp': '10', 'd2windms': '5', 'd2windkmh': '19', 'd2windr': 'ZW', 'd2windrgr': '225', 'd2neerslag': '90', 'd2zon': '20', 'alarm': '0', 'alarmtxt': ''}]])

For my RaspberryPi weather station I only need the values of 'temp' and 'lv' (luchtvochtigheid = humidity).
How do I pull these values from the dictionary?

Almost correct: data['liveweer'][0]['temp'] gives 23.6

The answer is data['liveweer'][0]['temp']
This gives 23.6

This doesn't seem too complicated -- can you say why you weren't able to do this yourself?

Because I have not been programming Pyhton for about 4 years. It is frightening how much details one forgets. I was put on the right track when the indexing was suggested. I did look for a similar question with a nested dictionary but did not find it.

I hope this helps.
data = {'plaats': 'Tilburg', 'timestamp': '1713019987', 'time': '13-04-2024 '
                                                                '16:53',
        'temp': '23.3', 'gtemp': '22.3', 'samenv': 'Licht bewolkt', 'lv': '48',
        'windr': 'ZW', 'windrgr': '225', 'windms': '6', 'winds': '4',
        'windk': '11.7', 'windkmh': '21.6', 'luchtd': '1020.5',
        'ldmmhg': '765', 'dauwp': '11.7', 'zicht': '40',
        'verw': 'Vandaag zonnige perioden, droog en vrij warm. Zondag frisser',
        'sup': '06:45', 'sunder': '20:35', 'image': 'lichtbewolkt',
        'd0weer': 'bewolkt', 'd0tmax': '22', 'd0tmin': '12', 'd0windk': '3',
        'd0windknp': '10', 'd0windms': '5', 'd0windkmh': '19', 'd0windr': 'ZW',
        'd0windrgr': '225', 'd0neerslag': '0', 'd0zon': '0',
        'd1weer': 'halfbewolkt', 'd1tmax': '15', 'd1tmin': '10',
        'd1windk': '3', 'd1windknp': '8', 'd1windms': '4', 'd1windkmh': '15',
        'd1windr': 'W', 'd1windrgr': '270', 'd1neerslag': '20', 'd1zon': '50',
        'd2weer': 'regen', 'd2tmax': '11', 'd2tmin': '7', 'd2windk': '3',
        'd2windknp': '10', 'd2windms': '5', 'd2windkmh': '19', 'd2windr': 'ZW',
        'd2windrgr': '225', 'd2neerslag': '90', 'd2zon': '20', 'alarm': '0',
        'alarmtxt': ''}
print(data['temp'])
print(data['lv'])
temp = data['temp']
lv =data['lv']


This is not the exact format of the data.  They said it was inside another dictionary with a "liveweer" key, and the dict_values output indicates that it is also inside of a list (possibly even two nested lists).

You'd first have to do: data = dict_values['liveweer'][0], then you can do data['temp']
